# Why do I get error "Login failed for user 'sa'" when running Cypress tests with MSSQL database?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, cypress

I'm trying to create to my web appplication, E2E tests with *cypress*. This application has tests with [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de) and [DUSK](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/dusk) and we want change these technologies for Cypress. I need connect the test Cypress to database that my database server — it's MSSQL in localhost, for now. In production also it's MSSQL. I read the documentation to do this, but my test returns:

```
Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

In my Management studio i can show my user `sa` ok, and i can to do login there:

[image: prueba]

To do my login I have this:

in my `cypress.json`

```json
{
    "db": {
        "userName": "sa",
        "password": "Secret-2-Secret",
        "server": "ES-8PV9BS3.local",
        "port": 1433,
        "options": {
            "database": "db_liquid_test_local",
            "encrypt": true,
            "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion" : true
        }
    }
}
```

in my `plugins/index.js`

```javascript
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');
  const dbConfig = require('../../cypress.json');

  module.exports = (on, config) => {
   tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(dbConfig.db);
   on('task', tasks);
 }`
```

in my `support/inex.js`

```javascript
import sqlServer from 'cypress-sql-server';
sqlServer.loadDBCommands();
```

and in my test, for example:

```javascript
describe('Example to Demonstrate SQL Database Testing in Cypress', () => {

   it('Create a Table', function () {
    cy.sqlServer('queryDb', "CREATE TABLE Persons (PersonID int, FirstName varchar(255), Address varchar(255), City varchar(255))")
})
```

I hope that my `cypress.json` is OK and my user is OK, but I can't connect to my MSSQL database and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

In my management I changed this option and it's activated:

- SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode

Also I change in Management console: `Protocol MSSQLSERVER` -> `TCP/IP` and it's activated

Comment: At a guess, the encryption is not setup correctly. SQL Server won't allow you to connect if you ask for an encrypted link and it's not able to negotiate the key properly (usually this is caused by a bad certificate). But again: just a guess. Also, **do not use sa like this**. The `sa` account should be **disabled** as soon as possible after setting up a new SQL Server and creating an alternate admin account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cypress-sql-server` package was last published 5 years ago, and the author has deleted the source code.

But fortunately you can look in `node_modules/cypress-sql-server` and see the source.

The package uses [Tedious](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious) and for the connection (plugin) it's code simply passes your `dbConfig.db` to Tedious:

```js
const Tedious = require('tedious')
const connection = new Tedious.Connection(dbConfig)
```

Tedious provides [examples](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/tree/master/examples) which appears to be up-to-date (package last published 5 days ago).

One example is [minimal.js](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/blob/master/examples/minimal.js)

```js
var Connection = require('../lib/tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('../lib/tedious').Request;

var config = {
  server: '192.168.1.212',
  authentication: {
    type: 'default',
    options: {
      userName: 'test',
      password: 'test'
    }
  },
  options: {
    port: 1433 // Default Port
  }
};

const connection = new Connection(config);

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Connection Failed');
    throw err;
  }

  executeStatement();
})
```

So to update your config to the current format, move credentials into the `authentication` object:

```js
{
  "db": {
    "server": "ES-8PV9BS3.local",
    "authentication": {
      "type": 'default',
      "options": {
        "userName": 'sa',
        "password": 'Secret-2-Secret'
      }
    },
    "options": {
      "database": "db_liquid_test_local",
      "port": 1433 // Default Port,
      "encrypt": true,
      "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion" : true
    }
  }
}
```

The full list of connection options is given [here](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/blob/f4d91f173fab0669d45ae513922585f748c11022/src/connection.ts#L495C1-L860C2)